# knex to transfer existing database schema in development env

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I already have Postgres data with the defined schema (over 50 tables). What is the best way using knex to set up the database schema in the development environment for existing database? any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Knex is not an ORM but just a query builder. It does not rely on any model file. You can just use it, by queryng your database using existing table names and existing column names.